# Programmatically linked buttons

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton

I am designing an app that requires me to have a grid of buttons each with four different states. Unselected, Selected, Hit, or Miss. I am trying to generate these buttons programatically but I am having trouble having just one of them remain selected. Is there a way that maybe I could put them into an array and then iterate over the array to unselect them? I looked into IBOutletCollections but those will not work because I want to create these buttons programmatically

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer: "put them into an array and then iterate over the array to unselect them" - this should work

Comment: NSArray references are "strong".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me where _lastSelectedButton is the id of the last selected button and the width is 25

```
-(void)unselect
{
if(_lastSelectedButton){
    //Unselect the last selected button However only change its background if is blue
    [[_lastSelectedButton layer] setBorderWidth:0.0f];
    if([_lastSelectedButton.titleLabel.text  isEqual: @"0"]){

        [[_lastSelectedButton layer] setBackgroundColor:[missColor CGColor]];
    }else if([_lastSelectedButton.titleLabel.text  isEqual: @"/"]){
        [[_lastSelectedButton layer] setBackgroundColor: [hitColor CGColor]];
    }
    else{
        [[_lastSelectedButton layer] setBackgroundColor:unselectedColor.CGColor];
    }
}
_lastSelectedButton = nil;

}
- (void)advanceSelection:(UIButton*)sender
```

{

```
int i = 0;
//Find the indice that the present selected thing is
for( UIButton *button in btnList )
{
    if( sender == button )
    {
        if((i >= (self.numberOfPlayers - 1) * width) &&(( i + 1) % 5 == 0)){
            //Then animated scroll to the next frame
            if (i + 1 == self.numberOfPlayers * width) {
                //then it is the last button
                [self unselect];


            }else{
                CGFloat x = (([_pageControl currentPage] + 1.0 ) * 320.0);
                [_scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, 0.0f) animated:YES];
                [self selection:btnList[i - (width * (self.numberOfPlayers - 1)) + 1]];
                [self scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:self.scrollView];
                self.pageControl.currentPage = _pageControl.currentPage + 1;
            }
        }else if(i >= ((self.numberOfPlayers - 1) * width)){
            //We want to move it up one
            //subtract width times hieght and ad one
            [self selection:btnList[i - (width * (self.numberOfPlayers - 1)) + 1]];

        }else{
            //To go one down add 25 (the width)
            [self selection:btnList[i + 25]];
        }
    }
    i++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you should check this demo I've learned in ***Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad cs193p***.

https://github.com/elilien/Matchismo

Comment: Im going to look through to see if that helps